# Huge hdd usage while gaming

Tags: linux, performance, wine, freeze, lag

For testing I tried to run Path of Exile and Guild Wars 2 on Ubuntu Budgie and Mint XFCE.
To run PoE I used steam.
To run GW2 I used Lutris.

When any game is fully loaded and I do not touch anithing all works fine. But when I start move character or camera fps drops to 4-5 and my HDD becomes crazy. I.e. GW2 process owerall hdd i/o is **35MB/s** everytime when I just stand in town. In PoE same situation. I tried to use SSD and problem becomes less fatal but anyway `spikes` didn't disappear.

The problem persists for all heavy games not only this two.

My PC:
i5 - 6600
GTX 1070
16Gb RAM
2x1Tb SATA HDD
256Gb SATA SSD

Comment: Sounds like swap thrashing, but 16GB of RAM should be plenty...? Are you sure it's all seated properly, etc? `/proc/meminfo` shows reasonable numbers? `htop` would show you the swap usage.

Comment: Yes, please click [edit] and post your results for /proc/meminfo and htop . Please do not respond with [Add Comments]; when new comments arrive, they can push other comments offscreen.